# Calling a constructor of a member object within the body of the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

Why am I not allowed to use the following syntax to call a constructor of a member object/different class in the body of the constructor of a class?

```
class Circle {
   double radius;

   public:
          Circle(double r) : radius(r) { }
          double area() {return radius*radius*3.14159265;}
};

class Cylinder {
   Circle base;
   double height;

   public:
          Cylinder(double r, double h)  {
          base(r);
          height = h;
          }
          double volume() {return base.area() * height;}
};
```

By the way I know I can call `Circle::Circle(double)` via `Cylinder(double,double)` using member initialization list like          `Cylinder(double r,double h) : base(r), height(r) {}` but still what's wrong with the former method that the compiler is generating this error?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: @Khan: [Should my constructors use “initialization lists” or “assignment”?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that when C++ begins the execution of the constructor code all the member variables must have been already constructed (what if you for example call a method of `Circle` before constructing it?).

If immediate construction is a problem then a possible solution is to add to your member a **default constructor** and the using **assignment** in the body of the constructor of the containing class.

You can imagine that native types like `int` or `double` do have a default constructor, that's why you can initialize them later (note however that for one of the many ugly quirks of the language the default constructor for an `int` or a `double` doesn't actually do anything **in this case** and you're not allowed to do anything with such a member except assigning it a value - for example reading it is not allowed).

You cannot use `base(r)` in the body because that's not a valid statement... following a name with an opening parenthesis is only used for function call, for initialization in a declaration or for member initialization in the constructor member initialization list.

If you provide `Circle` with a default constructor then you can do

```
Cylinder(double r, double h) {
    base = Circle(r);
    height = h;
}
```

Note however that the approach of constructing non-working objects to fix them later is not the best approach for C++. The language likes the idea that if an object is constructed then it's usable and deviations from this are considered only when necessary (C++11 drifted away a bit from this original path with move constructor... but that's another story).

Comment: It might be worth explaining the meaning of `base(r);` in the constructor body, since that is part of the question.

Comment: @Khan Zaid I do not understabd also what you want to calculate,is class Cylinder derived class?

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to handle this is an initializer list. Write the constructor of `Cylinder` like this:

```
Cylinder(double r, double h) : base(r), height(h) {}
```

The part between the `:` and the opening brace is the initializer list that constructs all the data members of the class *before the body of the constructor code is run*. That way, C++ ensures that your object is fully constructed even within the body of the constructor.

Since C++ ensures that all members are fully constructed before the body of the constructor is run, any attempt to call a constructor from the body of a constructor would reinitialize the object. While technically possible using placement-new, this is almost certainly not what you want to do.

The syntax `base(r);` within the body of the constructor tries to call the `operator()(double)` on the already fully constructed member. Since you didn't provide such an operator, your compiler complains.

Comment: _Since C++ ensures that all members are fully constructed before the body of the constructor is run...._ Isn't the job of a constructor to 'construct' the members of its object? Is member initialization a C++11 thing?

Comment: @KhanZaid Yes, and no. Yes it is the job of the constructor to initialize the members, but no, it is not the job of the constructor's *body* to do so. The body may do additional stuff with the members *after* their construction, but their construction is strictly the job of the initializer list. This basic principle holds true for all C++ standards. Note that the default constructors of the built-in types (like `int`, `float`, and `Foo*`) don't do anything, leaving the value of the members undefined. These can be "initialized" within the constructor's body. But that's really a special case.